# Finding the conjugates in $\mathbb{C}$ of a given number over a given field...

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I'm having somewhat of a difficult time understand what's being asked—and thus having a hard time answering the question:

> Find all conjugates in $\mathbb{C}$ of the given number over the given field:
>
> 1) $\sqrt{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$
>
> 2) $\sqrt{2}$ over $\mathbb{R}$
>
> ...
>
> 4) $\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$
>
> ...
>
> 7) $\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Now: This means, in the first example, I must first find the monic irreducible polynomial of least degree in $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\sqrt{2}$ is its zero, right? Is it right to go about doing this by saying "We know $\text{deg}( \text{irr}(\sqrt{2}, \mathbb{Q})) = 2$, so it has the form $x^2 + a_1x + a_2 = 0$ for $a_i \in \mathbb{Q}$ when $x = \sqrt{2}$. $a_2$ must be $-2$ and $a_1$ must be zero.

We have the polynomial $x^2 - 2$, for which $\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2}$ are both zeros, to the answer to this is $\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2}$."

In the case of$\sqrt{2}$ over $\mathbb{R}$, isn't $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{R}$—and isn't every polynomial reducible in $\mathbb{R}$?

For the third example, can I follow the same idea that I did in the first? Overall, I'm pretty confused about how to do these. I think there are a lot of holes in my understanding; I get what the question is asking *for*, but I'm not sure how to approach finding an answer.

Comment: Your first example is correct, and for your second you've shown that $\sqrt2$ is the only conjugate of $\sqrt2$ over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: It sounds like you understand what is being asked, and your method is basically fine: find the minimal polynomial and then split it. (4) and (7) have degree 4 so will be a bit trickier. (2) has degree 1 so is only tricky because it is so easy: $\sqrt{2}$ is the only answer. -- BTW not every polynomial is reducible over $\mathbb{R}$, $x-1$ and $x^2+1$ are irreducible.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Ah! Alright; every polynomial of degree *greater than* $2$ should be reducible over $\mathbb{R}$, yes? I think the part I'm having the hardest time doing is actually finding the minimal polynomial. Is this ultimately done by considering its degree and, basically, trial/erroring a solution?

Comment: Berci basically describes how to find minimal polynomials of numbers described as nested radical expressions. Occasionally Berci's method produces reducible polynomials, but hopefully your course will either prepare you for that, or not ask you those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you say $\sqrt2$ has no conjugate over $\Bbb R$ but has $-\sqrt2$ over $\Bbb Q$, which is correct.

For the other two, you just have to write up an equation that uses rationals for the given numbers, e.g. for 4)
$$\begin{align}x&=\sqrt2-\sqrt3 \\ x+\sqrt3&=\sqrt2\\x^2+2\sqrt3x+3&=2 \\
x^2+1&= - 2\sqrt3 x\\
\dots&\dots
\end{align}$$
From this you can also track back the other roots of the final equation.

Comment: Ah, alright. And just keep squaring until the only coefficients left are rational. Thanks, everyone. :)